# Google Sheets - IMPORTXML from livecoinwatch.com (Which XPath?)

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, cryptocurrency

I cannot seem to find the correct XPath to get the data from 1h and 24h price change @https://www.livecoinwatch.com

As far as I can see, the XPaths are;

1h

```
//*[@id="btchpc"]
```

24h

```
//*[@id="btcdpc"]
```

But, using the syntax (1h);

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.livecoinwatch.com/","//*[@id='btchpc']")
```

Returns an error; "Imported content is empty".

Changing it to

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.livecoinwatch.com/","//span[@id='btchpc']")
```

... doesn't work either.

I have another IMPORTXML function which works pefectly. It's for 24h change as well, from coinpuffs.com;

```
=IMPORTXML("https://coinpuffs.com/coin/BTC","//span[@id='coin-pct-change-value']")
```

Sorry if the above sounds completely ridiculous - I've only just started using the IMPORTXML function and I'm not really good at HTML and XML structures.

Thank you!

EDIT#1;

Further investigations are getting me closer to the target.
Instead of working out of the front page, I got into the respective coin's page, e.g. BTC and found the XPaths to the 1h, 24h and also 7d and 30d(!);

1h:

```
//*[@id="hpc"]
```

24h:

```
 //*[@id="dpc"]
```

7d:

```
//*[@id="wpc"]
```

30d:

```
//*[@id="mpc"]
```

Now, using the new URL and XPaths, I actually get some results, put they are parsed quite funny;

When I use the syntax (1h); in cell A1

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.livecoinwatch.com/price/Bitcoin-BTC","//*[@id='hpc']")
```

The result gets parsed into cell A3 and B1. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

So... Found the answer myself.

Had to add "span" to the syntax, i.e. it looks likes this;

1h

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.livecoinwatch.com/price/Bitcoin-BTC","//span[@id='hpc']")
```

Works!

Answer (score 0):

The page is no valid HTML so it seems google docs is not able to parse it. This however, loads the full table

`=IMPORTHTML("http://www.livecoinwatch.com","table",1)`

Comment: This would work much better than fetching XML per cell. 

But that query only includes the first (page of the) table, i.e. 50 entries/coins. How would I get all or a specified count of entries?
I just tested that syntax for coinpuffs, coinmarketcap and coingecko, and it works - but only includes entries that are on the first (page of) table.

Comment: Addition: CMC allows to view all coins; "https://coinmarketcap.com/all/views/all/" 
This provides data for all availble entries, But I'd like these data points for all available entries and accordingly additional data points as they appear on the others tables for the other sites.


Examples of such additional data points are;
livecoinwatch: 30d price change, Max Supply
Coingecko: Scores for Developer, Community, Public, Interest, Total

There might be more examples, for other sites, such as cryptocompare.com